# Где хранятся файлы сокета?

Tags: сокет, unix

Есть задача создать модель сокетов, чисто в исследовательских целей (Так что вопросов зачем, и нафига лучше не задавать). Раз в файловой системе UNIX "Все есть файл", в том числе и сокеты, можно ли взглянуть на них? Из чего они состоят? Их структура и так далее, чтобы приблизиться к реальной модели, если я ошибаюсь в чем-то, то буду рад выслушать как оно на самом деле работает.

Comment: В linux (и части других \*nix-ов) взглянуть можно в `/proc/net/...` Например, tcp сокеты в файле `/proc/net/tcp`. Подробности в [man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: [описание структуры socket: include/linux/net.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/net.h#L101) // *Раз в файловой системе UNIX "Все есть файл"* — кто-то вас очень жестоко обманул.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Раз в файловой системе UNIX "Все есть файл", в том числе и сокеты, ... Из чего они состоят?

Для начала, все специальные файлы в ФС (устройства, сокеты, именованные каналы) — это просто дескриптор файла, не имеющий никаких связанных данных в самой ФС. т.е. вопрос «из чего они состоят?» имеет не больше смысла, чем «что находится в пустом мешке?».

> Раз в файловой системе UNIX "Все есть файл", в том числе и сокеты, можно ли взглянуть на них?

Вообще говоря, это не так; а конкретнее это зависит от того, о каких сокетах идёт речь, если об обычных «интернет-сокетах» для TCP/UDP/IPX/что-то-ещё-более-странное, то они в большинстве реализаций не связаны ни с каким файлом в ФС. Если речь о Unix-сокетах (Unix Domain Socket или же локальные IPC-сокеты), то для них создаётся файл, указанный при связывании (*bind*) сокета. Традиционно большинство таковых располагаются в `/var/run`. Но, повторюсь, это чистая абстракция в памяти ядра и ни какой структуры на диске нет.

> Есть задача создать модель сокетов, чисто в исследовательских целей (Так что вопросов зачем, и нафига лучше не задавать).

Фраза звучит довольно бессмысленно, так что кое-какие пояснения тут не помешали бы..

Comment: В этом и дело, что пока что у меня каша в голове, и хотелось бы все это структурировать, сейчас больше вопросов, задача сделать модель уровня OSI, информация есть как работает, но вот как взаимодействие идет между всем, грубо говоря зачем нужен ip-адерс, если есть уникальный Mac-адрес каждого компа, ну и таких вроде глупых вопросов много, и во всем этом хотелось бы разобраться, на данный момент есть лабораторная работа в универе, где нужно смоделировать канальный уровень, но вот самая главный вопрос, нужен ли ip-адрес в данной модели, если канальный уровню на него все ровно?

Comment: Наверное я сформулировал не правильно вопрос, мне бы нужно знать, как вообще создается сокет, если это абстракция, то по какому принципу она работает, и тд. Просто одно дело, если я использую готовые функции на языке C, а другое дело, если я знаю как они работают. Просто хочу разобраться с сетями, да с корнями:)

Comment: @РобертГатри, сокет — это чисто программный интерфейс, удобная абстракция и API для программиста. к тому как работает сетевые протоколы оные имеют весьма поверхностное отношения; как в деталях реализованы сокеты — зависит от ОC, обычно это мало-кого интересует, так что основной источник информации по этому вопросу будут исходники... Обычно людей интересует два соседних уровня: детали того, какой именно API предоставляет подсистема сокетов (функции С и их ожидаемое поведение) и детали реализации нижележащих протоколов, которые  используются для передачи по сети.

Comment: @РобертГатри, для общего введения советую сначала почитать какую-нибудь книгу. От себя могу порекомендовать Д…Э.Камер — «Сети TCP/IP».

Comment: @РобертГатри, по поводу вопросов, то что глупые — ничего, однако желательно их чётко формулировать и они должны быть конкретными (не требовать написание целой книги для ответа); все спорные утверждения желательно приводить с последовательностью умозаключений, которые к ним привели или источником; по возможности, желательно снабжать примерами и также придерживаться принципа один пост — один вопрос. Но вопросы из серии «что от меня ожидается в этой лабораторной?» лучше адресовать преподавателю/методичкам/коллегам и практичней будет это выяснить до того, как интересоваться, «а как это сделать?».